# NUC randomly freezing - video hardware?

Tags: video, freeze

I have a NUC (NUC5CPYH: Celeron N3050, 8GB DDR3) that has begun randomly freezing.  (NOTE: It is currently running Linux Mint 19.1 "Tessa" w Cinnamon but this very much appears to be hardware-related -- read on.) I've used this hardware for three-plus years and only recently did it start doing this.  I've not been able to identify any pattern to the freeze other than it is random and appears not tied to any particular resource usage, heat (it happens a little while after booting up), or activity on the system.  It often occurs in conjunction with a repeated video pattern on the screen but when this occurs, the video pattern is also random; i.e., not the same pattern every time [image: sample photo] .

Based upon my experience, this feels like a video hardware issue.  But, thinking it could be memory, I did a couple tests running `memtest86+` at boot -- both tests froze at different points.  I then booted into the OS and tried memtester.  The first test, I tried `memtester 4G 2` just to see what it would do and that test completed with no errors noted.  I then did `memtester 8G 5` and it froze in the first loop while "Walking zeroes".  I then tried `memtester 4G 2` again and this time it also froze but in the second loop during the "Bit flip".  So, it doesn't appear to be memory-related.  Or, doesn't appear related to specific memory region.

During one test, I was running FireFox and received a "Crash notification" from the browser immediately before the system froze.

I should note that, this only began appearing after I decided to try installing Windows 10 Home on this system just to see how it would run.  Windows 10 did fine (though slow) for a while and then this behavior popped up.  Thinking this might be a Windows 10 or driver related issue, I took it back to Mint by wiping the drive during install.  However, as noted, the issue persists.

Comment: To eliminate the SSD or HHD, run from Live Mint on USB. Also, occasionally memory chips loosen (or fungal hyphae can even grow between contacts). Remove RAM, clean with 90% or stronger isopropanol, and reseat RAM.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks.  I already convinced it isn't the SSD as it froze during memtest ran from the GRUB menu booted from the DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the RAM.  After replacing the RAM module it is working fine with no freezes and no video anomalies.